# Can it time between blips, store the time between blips, subtract one time from the other and divide one time by another and display it?

Tags: timers, display

I am counting rotations of a shaft and timing events that occur during that rotation.  I wish to display
the event timing as a percentage of ~1/4 of the rotation timing.  This would involve recording the rotation time, dividing that number by 3.6 and dividing that number by the value of the event timer, then displaying that percentage on an LCD array.

Comment: I don't really understand, what you are trying to do. I also don't understand, what exactly your problem is with writing the code. For normal timing the `millis()` and `micros()` function can be used, which give you the time since startup in milliseconds or microseconds respectively

Comment: your last sentence is a rough outline of the program function ... `This would involve recording the rotation time, dividing that number by 3.6 and dividing that number by the value of the event timer, then displaying that percentage on an LCD array.` .... add much, much more detail ... basically, turn it into a flow chart that you can convert into code

Comment: Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Please also note, that these sites are neither services to get a program written nor teaching in depth. Show us some code, describe the specific problem and post a detailled question. As your question is now, the answer is simply "yes."

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the millis() function.
It returns the time that passed in milliseconds since the board power up.

With this function you can find the time delta, and achieve all the described calculations.

[For more information](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/)